# css vh vw and svg rectangle in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a responsive svg layout for presentations that uses the same aspect as powerpoint or keynote (1024 x 768). I use the following code which works fine in chrome but not in Safari (see attached snapshots). I am on mbp 13 touch bar and Safari 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>

body{
    margin:0;
    display:block;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

body svg {
  /*border: 1px solid #C1543D;*/ /*for testing*/
  display:block;
  margin: auto;
}

.background {
  fill: white;
}

</style>

<body>
  <svg id='mainSVG' width='100%' height='100%' viewbox='0,0, 1024, 768'>
    <rect x='0px' y='0px' width='100%' height='100%' class='background'></rect>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Safari
[image: Safari]

Chrome
[image: chrome]

Comment: Have you tried removing the margins from the body tag?

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Comment: Maybe you could just adjust the size in pixels with javascript. I've read many other bugs about safari not computing viewport units properly

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be messing with the body. Why don't you try creating a container and apply those values to the container instead? Try using the following code:

```
html,
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  width:100vw;
  height:50vh;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6n4yLv4f/

edit: I realized what you wanted as soon as I posted my previous reply in the comments. Here is the correct solution you are after:

Use `viewBox` attribute as follows:

```
<svg id='mainSVG' viewBox="0 0 1024 768" height="100%"></svg>
```

And use this css:

```
svg {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is also a working fiddle. You were using the `viewBox`attribute wrong that was the problem...

https://jsfiddle.net/6n4yLv4f/2/

Comment: On second thought I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve is possible. You can stretch an SVG because it accepts CSS properties but not elements like rect. You can keep the rectangle's ratio though if you use the viewBox property on the svg. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I modified the question to reflect my actual goal

Comment: So, what you are actually trying to achieve is a standard ratio svg, not a rectangle inside an svg, is this correct? If so, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n4yLv4f/1/